# Cannot Refresh UITableView Data With SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

**Intent:** I have a simple UITableView that I set up programmatically (no IB), and a segmented control which will replace the table's array and refresh the view.

**Problem:** When I press either of the segmented control buttons, the new data set output to the log is correct, but the tableView is not refreshed.

If I scroll the table, the cells get replaced with the correct data, but I want the cells to refresh instantly (without scrolling). When I initially load the table, my NSLog from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is written, however it never appears again upon pressing the button. Am I not setting up the delegate correctly?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *tableObjects;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    //Create toggle frame
    UILabel *toggleFrame = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    toggleFrame.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:toggleFrame];

    //Create the segmented control
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Numbers", @"Letters", nil];

    //Set font size
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeFont];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]              initWithItems:itemArray];
    [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(70, 5, 180, 30);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(showList:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];


    //Create frame with tableview in it
    CGRect tableframe = CGRectMake(0,40,320,400);

    //Instantiate the TableView
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableframe style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

-(void) showList:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        tableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",tableObjects);
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } else {

        tableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alpha", @"Bravo", @"Charlie", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",tableObjects);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Number of Rows Called");
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate your table view you are doing:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableframe style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

You should do:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableframe style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Heliem. This solved the problem, but it makes me less confident! Why is it correct to initialize this table to self.tableView and not to a pointer to the instance of UITableView? Is it because of the property declaration in the .h file?

Comment: simply because in the showList method you call [self.tableView reloadData] to, well, reload the data. But you have not assigned anything to self.tableView.. unless you make self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc(...)] that variable will be always nil

Comment: Hmmm. OK. I will do some more reading about self, then. I do appreciate your help.